# HorizontalLayout with wrap components?

Tags: java, frameworks, vaadin

I'm creating a UI and using a HorizontalLayout for organization my components. 
The problem is my window is large because components are added only one row.

how to I do a wrap for my components in HorizontalLayout ?

thanks

Comment: what framework you are using to create the layout?? or how are you creating the layout? please post the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HorizontalLayout can only lay the components horizontally as its name suggests. You can try CssLayout which wraps the components by default. Or what you can try is you can customize the width of components and set it to null like for a label its label.setWidth(null) and try using this technique with the ExpandRatio(Component, 1.0f) method. Suppose you have three components the set the width of the left and the right component to null and then set ExpandRatio to 1.0f to the middle label. You can try using this idea to more than three components.